# showing a bound on a complex functional

Tags: real-analysis

I have the following problem:

*Let X be a complex normed linear space and f: X $\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a complex linear functional. Show that $|f(x)| \le ||x||$ for all $x \in X$ if and only if Ref(x) $\le ||x||$ for all $x \in X$.*

I've shown the forward direction using the polar form of f(x), but I'm having trouble showing the reverse. Can anyone give me a hint (but not the solution) please? I'm pretty stuck.

Answer (score 2):

For each $x$, find an $\alpha_{x}$ such that $|\alpha_{x}|=1$ and $|f(x)|=\alpha_{x}f(x)=f(\alpha_{x}x)=\text{Re}f(\alpha_{x}x)$. Note that $\text{Im}f(\alpha_{x}x)=0$ in this case. So $|f(x)|\leq\|\alpha_{x}x\|=|\alpha_{x}|\|x\|=\|x\|$.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I follow the idea, but I'm unable to find such an $\alpha_{x}$. How can I guarantee that the imaginary part of f would be zero? I'm sorry, I do appreciate your help.

Comment: Say, for a nonzero complex number $u$, let $\alpha=\dfrac{\overline{u}}{|u|}$, then $\alpha u=|u|$.

Comment: Because $|f(x)|$ is a real number and $|f(x)|=\text{Re}f(\alpha_{x}x)+i\text{Im}f(\alpha_{x}x)$, so the imaginary part must be zero.

Comment: Okay, thank you for all of your help. I'm going to keep working on it. You've been very helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Let $g:= \text{Re}f$ and $h(x):= \text{Im}f$. For $x \in X$ we have

$f(ix)=g(ix)+ih(ix)$. Since $f(ix)=if(x)$, we get

$$ ig(x)-h(x)=g(ix)+ih(ix).$$

Thus $-g(ix)=h(x)$ and therefore $f(x)=g(x)-ig(ix)$. It follows that

$$g(x)^2 \le g(x)^2+g(ix)^2=|f(x)|^2 \le ||x||^2.$$

Consequence: $|g(x)| \le ||x||$ and therefore

$$-||x|| \le g(x) \le ||x||.$$

Comment: Thank you for your help, unfortunately I've already solved this direction. I was asking about the other direction, however I believe I was able to get it with the help of the other commenter. Thank you for your help.